# iterating through an array with ngFor, "Identifier not defined"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

When iterating through an array with ngFor I get the error:

"Identifier 'expenseitem' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member"

The identifier IS defined in the imported model.ts file.
What could I be doing wrong??

**receipts.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Expenses Total: {{ totalExpenses | currency:'GBP'}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button routerLink="/addform">
        <ion-icon name="add" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" text-center>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>
          {{ loadedExpenses[0].timestamp }}
        </ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-img [src]="loadedExpenses[0].imageUrl"></ion-img>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>{{ loadedExpenses[0].amount | currency:'GBP' }}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" text-center>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let expenseitem of loadedExpenses"></ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img [src]="expenseitem.imageUrl"></ion-img>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>{{ expenseitem.timestamp }}</h2>
          <p>{{ expenseitem.amount }}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**receipts.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ExpensedataService } from '../expensedata.service'
import { Expenseitem } from '../expenseitem.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-receipts',
  templateUrl: './receipts.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./receipts.page.scss'],
})
export class ReceiptsPage implements OnInit {
  loadedExpenses: Expenseitem[];

  constructor(private expensedataService: ExpensedataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadedExpenses = this.expensedataService.expenseitems;
  }

}
```

**expenseitem.model.ts**

```
export class Expenseitem {

    constructor(public id: string, public timestamp: number, public amount: number, public imageUrl: string
        ) { }
}
```

Comment: did you try to log what is `this.expensedataService.expenseitems;` giving you back.
try something like this `console.log(this.expensedataService.expenseitems);`
Because it can be that there you dont have data.

Comment: If the this.expensedataService.expenseitems returns a promise or something like that, the ngFor will not work. Can you show the function inside your service?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my error.

I made a stupid mistake with the closing `</ion-item>` tag:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let expenseitem of loadedExpenses"></ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img [src]="expenseitem.imageUrl"></ion-img>
```

of course you must iterate inside the tag you are in or it will not work. So by moving `</ion-item>` to contain my iteration it now works.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let expenseitem of loadedExpenses">
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img [src]="expenseitem.imageUrl"></ion-img></ion-item>
```

Thank you for your responses and apologies for wasting time!